# Using rsync to copy directory structure only keeping certain files

Tags: terminal, rsync

I am using this code

```
find  /path/to/directories/ -d  -iname "*modified.tif" -type f -exec rsync -R --relative -v {} test/ \;
```

to copy the directories within orig_images and only keeping *modified.tif files. However, my result looks like

```
test/path/to/directories
```

whereas I want it to look like

```
test/directories
```

It's trivial to move the directories into test/ but I'd like to be able to do this in the future without having to add that extra step. How can I accomplish this? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the directory properly:

`cd /path/to/; find  directories/ -d  -iname "*modified.tif" -type f -exec rsync -R --relative -v {} test/ \;`
You may adapt the target by set the `test/` to the directory you want.